# How far can Spider-man shoot his web with his web-shooters?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

In recent gameplay demo of Marvel Spider-man ps4, I noticed that when he web zipping the web went pretty far (actually, incredibly far). Is that really true that his web can shoot really far? Is there a maximum distance his web can shoot?

My question is about the web shooter capability.

Comment: I've added an "auxillary" question that should prevent it from being closed for whatever reason a user may want to without changing your question, if you disagree with my edit feel free to roll back.

Comment: Does https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100578/how-long-can-the-spider-mans-web-stretch answer your question?

Comment: Thanks man  Edlothiad

Comment: “Is that really true that his web can shoot really far?” You’ll have to define “really far”.

Comment: I mean like maybe more than 100 meters long

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can the Spider-Man's web stretch?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100578/how-long-can-the-spider-mans-web-stretch)

Comment: Well not really. I think my question is about the web shooter capability

Comment: There is an answer there that discusses that, but I suppose I ought to ask the question, what sort of canon are you looking at? Comics? Movies? Video games? The TV series? The cartoon?

Comment: I think from the comics.

Comment: I don't believe the proposed duplicate really answers the question, "how far can Spider-Man's webshooters shoot a web?" There's a calculation on how far he *did* shoot a web in one case, but not a general distance answer. This has nothing specifically to do with the *elasticity* of the webbing, or how *much* of it he can produce.

Answer (score 3):

Not a definitive source, but the [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Web-Shooters) estimates a range of 60 feet.

> The web line's tensile strength has been estimated to be 120 pounds
>   per square millimeter of cross section. The 300 p.s.i. pressure in
>   each cartridge is sufficient to force a stream of the complex web
>   pattern an estimated 60 feet. (It goes significantly farther if
>   Spider-Man shoots it in a ballistic parabolic arc.)

There's plenty of room for argument here, but it's a base to to start from.  That doesn't allow for wind, elevation, or any other number of factors either.

One could be cynical and say that it fires as long (or as short) as the plot demands.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe a figure has ever been given in the actual stories, but several of Spider-Man's [Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe) entries state the following (emphasis mine):

> The 300 p.s.i. of pressure in each cartridge is sufficient to force a stream of the complex web pattern **an estimated 60 feet** (significantly farther if shot in a ballistic parabolic arc).

[The Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Vol 1 #10](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_1_10)

[image: Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe v1 010 022]

[The Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Vol 2 #12](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_2_12)

[image: Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe v2 012 030]

[The Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Vol 4 #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_4_2)

[image: Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe - Spider-Man 2004 037]

[Spider-Man: The Ultimate Guide](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man_The_Ultimate_Guide_Vol_1_1) has this to say (emphasis mine again):

> The pressure in Spider-Man's web cartridges is enough to propel a single strand of webbing **up to 50 yards**, but thicker strands and more complex web patterns can't reach nearly as far.

[image: Spider-Man - The Ultimate Guide 001 028-029]